# Have I applied for my Carte de Sejour incorrectly? Does having a long stay visa affect my application?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, france, eu-spouses, long-stay

I am a UK citizen, married to a German citizen residing in France. I tried to apply for carte sejour earlier when I first joined him in April. But he did not have the required documents for employment at the time.

He applied for self employment/auto entrepreneur but it took longer than expected to sort his documents from Germany. My 90 day visa was running out so I went to the UK in July, and applied for Long-stay 6 months Visitors visa so I could be with him again, and Joined him back in September. I only did this as the 90 day visa would only be valid again in October.

He finally had evidence of work in France for proof of my carte Sejour, so I applied online in the end of October.

It's been nearly a month, but I don't know if I need to validate my long stay visa if I am applying for this nor how long it would take as I would like to work too. And get my residency before my 6 months run out.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, but thanks for reading.

Comment: As the spouse of a German citizen in France you don't have to worry very much about any of this.  If he is not working or registered as a job seeker, you can nonetheless remain indefinitely there in France without regard to any 90-day or three-month period if you have sufficient resources to support yourselves.  Did you consider applying for a _carte de séjour_ on that basis?

Answer (score 3):

> He finally had evidence of work in France for proof of my carte Sejour, so I applied online in the end of October.
>
> It's been nearly a month, but I don't know if I need to validate my long stay visa if I am applying for this nor how long it would take as I would like to work too. And get my residency before my 6 months run out.

As the spouse of an EU citizen exercising the right of free movement under union law, you don't need to be in possession of any particular document to remain in France.  You don't need a long-stay visa, much less to validate one.  All you need is a valid passport and to be able to prove your relationship to your husband and that he is German.

Failure to meet the administrative requirement to register with the French authorities and get a *carte de séjour* can only lead to a fine (presently €200).  You can't be expelled nor face any other punishment.  Furthermore, once you've applied, you've fulfilled your obligation as any further delay is the responsibility of the French state and cannot be held against you.

To restate: as long as you apply within three months of your most recent arrival in France, you've met your obligation.

References:

https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F35495/0_1_1?idFicheParent=N110#0_1_1

> Comment demander la carte de séjour ?
>
> Vous devez faire votre demande sur le site de l'ANEF (Administration Numérique des Etrangers en France)  dans les 3 mois de votre entrée en France.
>
> Attention
>
> En cas de séjour irrégulier (demande déposée plus de 3 mois après l'entrée), un droit de visa de régularisation de 200 € à régler par timbres fiscaux sera exigé lors de la remise de la carte

My translation:

> How to apply for the residence card?
>
> Apply at ANEF (Administration Numérique des Etrangers en France) within three months of entering France.
>
> Attention
>
> In case of irregular presence (application submitted more than three months after entry), a "regularization" fee of €200, to be paid with tax stamps, is required before the card can be issued.